# TypeSafe Activator installation error

Tags: playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I'm having a problem installing Typesafe Activator. I downloaded the latest version from their website, extracted it and then opened activator.bat, it starts the webserver and the keeps spamming an error until it crashes:

[image: Stacktrace]

It's very weird because it worked before, but I kind of 'deinstalled' it by deleting all my Activator files (inlcuding the .activator directory in C:\Users\wouter). Now I downloaded it again and I keep getting this error, I tried fixing it by deleting the .activator directory but that doesn't work. Maybe there are still files hided from my previous installation.

It is very frustrating since I can't find any similar issues on the internet and just reinstalling does not work...

I hope you guys can help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same thing, and here is how I fixed it:

In my username directory (Windows 7 x64) there was a folder named ".sbt". In there was a folder named "boot".

In there were a handful of scala folders, each folder a different version.

I deleted all of them except the latest scala version folder (scala-2.11.1).

Once I did that, Activator booted up successfully (right click on the Activator.bat file).

Comment: This workaround worked for me again today, upgrading from Activator 1.2.11 to 1.2.12.