# typesafe activator ui not launching

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: req
uirement failed: Source file 'C:\Users\shriv_000\.activator\1.3.6\templates\inde
x.db_e25b80033130c08.tmp' is a directory.]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_
2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_
2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfu
n$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:205) [play_2.11-2.3.9.jar
:2.3.9]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfu
n$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:202) [play_2.11-2.3.9.jar
:2.3.9]
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.s
cala:36) [scala-library.jar:0.13.8]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file '
C:\Users\shriv_000\.activator\1.3.6\templates\index.db_e25b80033130c08.tmp' is a
 directory.
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:219) ~[scala-library.jar:0.13.8]
        at sbt.IO$.copyFile(IO.scala:584) ~[client-all-2-11-0.3.5.jar:0.3.5]
        at sbt.IO$.move(IO.scala:786) ~[client-all-2-11-0.3.5.jar:0.3.5]
        at activator.package$RichIO$.createViaTemporary$extension(package.scala:
30) ~[activator-templates-cache-1.0-a0afb008ea619bf9d87dc010156cddffa8a6f880.jar
:1.3.6]
        at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository$$anonfun$r
esolveIndexTo$1.apply(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala:228) ~[activator-templat
es-cache-1.0-a0afb008ea619bf9d87dc010156cddffa8a6f880.jar:1.0-a0afb008ea619bf9d8
7dc010156cddffa8a6f880]
[info] application - onStop received closing down the app
```

I am at activator 1.3.6

I have seen [TypeSafe Activator installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726244/typesafe-activator-installation-error) and it might be different then my problem. I have been able to create and launch a play project.

The solution provided there did not work for me.

I see this problem frequently.

Comment: have you tried to remove this directory and rerun activator `C:\Users\shriv_000\.activator\1.3.6\templates\inde
x.db_e25b80033130c08.tmp` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried all kinds of clean ups like removing from folder 1.3.6

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Try to execute activator as an administrator.

Comment: please check this [UJRL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: In particular, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer would be a good read. Thanks for your contribution.